# Existence and Uniqueness for a nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have the first-order nonlinear ODE: $$(y’)^2+y^2=1$$

Upon inspection, we see that $y(t)=\pm1$ and $y(t)=\pm\sin(t+a)$. ‘Another’ solution one sees upon inspection is $y(t)=\pm\cos(t+a),$ but this is contained in the other solution ($\pm\sin(t+a)$).

My question is:

Are these solutions unique? Are there any others and how do we know? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The usual theorems on existence and uniqueness do not hold for such kind of differential equations, because this is not an ODE: this is a Differential Algebraic Equation.

Comment: @downvoter - I gave my thoughts, tagged it correctly, and was not convoluted. Please let me know how I can improve my question!

Comment: I am not an expert on such objects, so I feel difficult to give advice on such matters, but [this Math.SE Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407707/differential-algebra-and-differential-algebraic-equations) should be useful for understanding the differences between DAEs and ODEs. For some references, I would advice you to have a look at [this Scholarpedia entry](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Differential-algebraic_equations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are also "piecewise" solutions such as 
$$ y(t) = \cases{-1 & if $t \le -\pi/2$ \cr 
                \sin(t) & if $-\pi/2 \le t \le \pi/2$\cr
                 1  & if $t \ge \pi/2$\cr} $$

For each initial condition $y(t_0) = y_0$ with $-1 < y_0 < 1$, there are two solutions, one increasing and one decreasing, as long as $|y|$ stays less than $1$.  But once you hit $y = \pm 1$, there is no more uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the ODE in the normal form $y'=f(y)$. Once it is written in this form, check if $f$ is Lipschitz. If $f$ is Lipschitz, the initial value problem (i.e., when you specify the value $y(0)$) has a unique solution.

In your example, we have 2 normal forms, or 2 branches to consider:
$$
f(y)=\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}.
$$
Hence, in the best case scenario, we would get exactly 2 solutions for a given initial data $y(0)$. Sticking to reals for simplicity, we have the following.

- Exactly 2 *local* solutions if $-1<y(0)<1$.
- The branches of $f$ are non-Lipschitz at $y=\pm1$, so more than 2 solutions if $y(0)=\pm1$.
- Different solutions can be glued together at $t$ whenever $y(t)=\pm1$.

Comment: What happens if $f(y)$ isn’t uniquely determined in our case? $f(y)=\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}$

Comment: @livingtolearn-learningtolive: It just means that you have 2 cases to consider. You can see that *unless* the initial data is $y(0)=\pm1$, each branch has a unique solution locally in time. For $y(0)=\pm1$, each branch is non-Lipschitz, so uniqueness is not guaranteed. This is the reason why you lose uniqueness at $t$ whenever $y(t)=\pm1$.